# Use Java XML Transformer with a network proxy

Tags: java, xml, networking, transform

I want to transform an XML file with `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, but my web access passes through a proxy.

I've tried using a new `URIResolver` with the transformer, but that didn't work. How can I instruct the transformer to use the proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general network access from the JDK, one option is to pass JDK args at startup.

Something like:

```sh
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 ... MyTransformerClass
```

Often a better solution is set the option programatically in your application, using values you've read from your config file.

Something like:

```java
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", myConfig.getProxyHost());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", myConfig.getProxyPort());
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html for all the options

However, in the specific example of XML processing where you need to resolve XSD, DTD etc. It's almost always better to have a local copy of the resource as you've tried and specify a javax.xml.stream.XMLResolver to your parser to load the local copy rather than the remote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the proxy in your application.

First, you need to create a class that extends `java.net.Authenticator` like this one:

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class SimpleAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private String username, password;

    public SimpleAuthenticator(String username, String password) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Second, initialize Authenticator in your code:

```
SimpleAuthenticator sm = new simpleAuthenticator("user", "pass")
Authenticator.setDefault(sm);
```

Third, pass port, proxy as system properties to your application. With jetty and maven it would look like:

```
mvn jetty:run -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=proxy.company.com -DproxyPort=8080
```